# IUserStore<TUser>.CreateAsync : how to indicate failure in custom implementation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am writing a custom implementation for IUserStore. The signature of the create method is:

```
public async virtual Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
```

And that makes sense considering the core interface IUserStore in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity is (which is the same).

However the interface of the UserManager class defined in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity is :

```
public virtual Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user);
```

My problem is  I don't see how I should pass this IdentityResult to the UserManager since the return type in the store is simply "Task". I have a custom logic to determine if a user can or cannot be created, so I really need to tell the outcome of CreateAsync to the UserManager.

Any idea ?

Comment: In your application flow, when a user cant be created, is that an exceptional case or is that part of normal flow of execution?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thank you for your interest ! It is part of the normal flow of execution. To give more context, I am doing my custom implementation of ASP.Identity in a different assembly, this is why I want to handle this case directly in the UserStore to keep the client focused on the business logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [source code for `UserManager.CreateAsync`](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-rtm-140226/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core) (this is for Identity 2.0) you can see that prior to calling `IUserStore.CreateAsync`, it makes a call to `IIdentityValidator<TUser>.ValidateAsync`, which is responsible to actually return the relevant `IdentityResult` object:

```
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user)
{
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        await UpdateSecurityStampInternal(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var result = await UserValidator.ValidateAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return result;
        }
        if (UserLockoutEnabledByDefault && SupportsUserLockout)
        {
            await GetUserLockoutStore().SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user, true).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        await Store.CreateAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return IdentityResult.Success;
}
```

The main purpose of `IUserStore.CreateAsync` is to make the call to the underlying data source which saves the data. It seems that you make actually want to implement `IIdentityValidator<TUser>` and set it on your `UserManager` instance.

Comment: Ahah we posted at the exact same time ! Thanks for your help, I'll definitely have a look at IUserValidator

Comment: @red2nb I also browsed the source on GitHub, then noticed it was for ASP.NET 5. So I looked on SymbolSource instead. The interface is actually called `IIdentityValidator<TUser>`, i've updated my answer

Comment: Actually there's still an issue with that. The validation I am doing, is an integrity check. By relying on the UserValidator I am lacking the context in which this Validator is called (creation, update, etc...). I guess this validator is mainly there to check if Properties have been set and this sort of things.

Comment: I'll just put the checks in the client, let's compromise on the design. I'll create an ad-hoc extension method there, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Can you please help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275597/how-to-give-custom-implementation-of-updateasync-method-of-asp-net-identity

Answer (score 2):

The answer is [in the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity), here's a part of the implementation in the  UserManager at time of writing :

```
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        await UpdateSecurityStampInternal(user, cancellationToken);
        var result = await ValidateUserInternal(user, cancellationToken);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return result;
        }
        if (Options.Lockout.EnabledByDefault && SupportsUserLockout)
        {
            await GetUserLockoutStore().SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user, true, cancellationToken);
        }
        await UpdateNormalizedUserNameAsync(user, cancellationToken);
        await Store.CreateAsync(user, cancellationToken);
        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }
```

So basically they always return true. This means that in the current version, putting my creation checks in the UserStore goes against the intended usage of the framework.

However I have noticed that this will be changed in the next release. The IUserStore interface will become :

```
Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

And the UserManager implementation :

```
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        await UpdateSecurityStampInternal(user);
        var result = await ValidateUserInternal(user);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return result;
        }
        if (Options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers && SupportsUserLockout)
        {
            await GetUserLockoutStore().SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user, true, CancellationToken);
        }
        await UpdateNormalizedUserNameAsync(user);
        await UpdateNormalizedEmailAsync(user);

        return await Store.CreateAsync(user, CancellationToken);
    }
```

So putting the creation logic in the UserStore will be possible at that time. This will be a way better design in my opinion as the client shouldn't have to handle the integrity concerns.

Comment: *So basically they always return true.* If you look again at the code, you'll see that if the call to `ValidateAsync` returns anything other than success, then it's `IdentityResult` will return which will contain the errors. So it isn't actually always returning true.

Comment: Can you please help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275597/how-to-give-custom-implementation-of-updateasync-method-of-asp-net-identity