# Custom implementation of ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, async-await, task, asp.net-web-api2, identity

I'm using various resources to try and implement an Identity system with MS Access for an AngularJS app.
I created classes which implement the Identity interfaces I need, and I'm stuck at the stage of creating the Account controller (which will be the API for registeration, login, etc).

The class `UserStore` implements `IUserStore` and has the `CreateAsync` method:

```
public Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
{
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
    }

    var result = userTable.Insert(user);

    return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

`AccountController` implements `ApiController` and has the `Register` method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(IdentityUser user)
{
    var result = await _userStore.CreateAsync(user);

    if (result == 0)
    {
        return InternalServerError();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

`userTable.Insert(user)` returns an `int` indicating the number of rows affected in the DB table. The line `var result = await _userStore.CreateAsync(user);` throws an error, saying it actually returns `void`, and so `void` cannot be assigned to `var` (or to anything else).

I'm having a hard time understanding how to write the `Register` method and the `CreateAsync` method so that they will work together.

BTW, I thought I should give up the whole `async` thing and just make `CreateAsync` and `Register` return the int value as-is, but I can't do that since `UserStore` implements `IUserStore'.

Comment: There's an example in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927571/iuserstoretuser-createasync-how-to-indicate-failure-in-custom-implementation) which may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the return type cannot be passed from the `CreateAsync` as it is simply a `Task` return. It would need to be `Task<int>` but you cannot do that since it's implementing the `IUserStore` interface. Why do you need the result, I'm assuming you do not?

Try this instead:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(IdentityUser user)
{
    await _userStore.CreateAsync(user);
    return Ok();
}
```

Additionally, consider making `userTable.Insert(user)` an `async` call if at all possible.

I would suggest not giving up on `async/await`. Especially for I/O bound operations on a web site like this, they really make your application usable.

If you're really concerned about whether or not the insert might be problematic, try this instead:

```
public async Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
{
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
    }

    var existingUser = await this.FindByIdAsync(user.Id);
    if (existingUser != null)
    {
        await this.UpdateAsync(user);
    }
    else
    {
        userTable.Insert(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275597/how-to-give-custom-implementation-of-updateasync-method-of-asp-net-identity

Comment: @Learning if you're targeting **ASP.NET** and not **ASP.NET Core**, I am not as familiar with that... I have been working on a huge **ASP.NET Core** project therefore I'm more up-to-speed with this framework, so to speak.

Comment: Yes I am targetting asp.net core and your this answer shows that you have good understanding on Microsoft asp.net identity.can you give me any idea or suggestion on how to update password hashed with Microsoft identity in database table??